# Google Play коллбек серверу об оплате подписки

Tags: php, google-play, android-billing

Есть андроид приложение и бек к нему на PHP. В приложении планируется оплата подписки через Google Play Billing. Есть ли возможность получать коллбеки от Google Play на url сервера, для отслеживания оплат каждый месяц?

Пытался гуглить, все выглядит неоднозначно. К примеру в Apple Pay четко есть дока, в которой сказано что надо предоставить url, на который будет приходить POST запрос. А у гугла что?

Comment: Для этого вам придется делать вызов самостоятельно из вашего приложения на ваш бэк при обработке метода [onPurchasesUpdated](https://adapty.io/blog/android-in-app-purchases-google-play-billing-library-part-2) в приложении.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это не подойдет так, как подписка оплачивается каждый месяц в фоновом режиме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настроить Pub/Sub и push подписку на нужный урл

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.